# Duplicate binary info in publishing error message

Tags: 2013, web8.5, binary

I am new to Web 8.5 and recently moved to this version. I have noticed the following, when a Page or Component is published in earlier versions (2013) and if  publishing failed due to duplicate binary, the error used to have the tcm ids mentioned. Whereas in 8.5, I could see only some error related to `BinaryWorker` but with no info on tcm-ids of the binaries.

Let me know if there is a way to get the tcm-ids written in Publish Transaction error message itself so that the author/editor could himself correct it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this will be pretty hard to achieve, if at all possible. The cd_core log file of the deployer will contain a more helpful message (although in the form of a warning, there is no error logged at all in this scenario, which I find odd). But I wouldn't know how to present this message to the editor.

Couldn't you focus on preventing this situation in the first place? This kind of conflict only occurs if you wrote your own code to manage the locations of the binaries you publish. This makes you, in a way, responsible for preventing duplicates. Without knowing anything about your implementation, the thought struck me that perhaps you can prevent this from happening with the event system somehow?